# R&W with AXI4 slave

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, firmware, vivado, vivado-hls

I'm a begginer in VHDL and Vivado and I need to establish communication between slave and master; exactly I need to read and write. I mean, my slave is a memory and my master is a DDR controller.
I used the wizard to create an IP but I am pretty lost... This is what the wizard returns:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity axitest_v1_0 is
    generic (
        -- Users to add parameters here

        -- User parameters ends
        -- Do not modify the parameters beyond this line


        -- Parameters of Axi Slave Bus Interface S00_AXI
        C_S00_AXI_ID_WIDTH  : integer   := 1;
        C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH    : integer   := 32;
        C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH    : integer   := 7;
        C_S00_AXI_AWUSER_WIDTH  : integer   := 0;
        C_S00_AXI_ARUSER_WIDTH  : integer   := 0;
        C_S00_AXI_WUSER_WIDTH   : integer   := 0;
        C_S00_AXI_RUSER_WIDTH   : integer   := 0;
        C_S00_AXI_BUSER_WIDTH   : integer   := 0
    );
    port (
        -- Users to add ports here

        -- User ports ends
        -- Do not modify the ports beyond this line


        -- Ports of Axi Slave Bus Interface S00_AXI
        s00_axi_aclk    : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_aresetn : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_awid    : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awaddr  : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awlen   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awsize  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awburst : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awlock  : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_awcache : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awprot  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awqos   : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awregion    : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awuser  : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_AWUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_awvalid : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_awready : out std_logic;
        s00_axi_wdata   : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_wstrb   : in std_logic_vector((C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_wlast   : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_wuser   : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_WUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_wvalid  : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_wready  : out std_logic;
        s00_axi_bid : out std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_bresp   : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_buser   : out std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_BUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_bvalid  : out std_logic;
        s00_axi_bready  : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_arid    : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_araddr  : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arlen   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arsize  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arburst : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arlock  : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_arcache : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arprot  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arqos   : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arregion    : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s00_axi_aruser  : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ARUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_arvalid : in std_logic;
        s00_axi_arready : out std_logic;
        s00_axi_rid : out std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_rdata   : out std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_rresp   : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_rlast   : out std_logic;
        s00_axi_ruser   : out std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_RUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s00_axi_rvalid  : out std_logic;
        s00_axi_rready  : in std_logic
    );
end axitest_v1_0;

architecture arch_imp of axitest_v1_0 is

    -- component declaration
    component axitest_v1_0_S00_AXI is
        generic (
        C_S_AXI_ID_WIDTH    : integer   := 1;
        C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH  : integer   := 32;
        C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH  : integer   := 7;
        C_S_AXI_AWUSER_WIDTH    : integer   := 0;
        C_S_AXI_ARUSER_WIDTH    : integer   := 0;
        C_S_AXI_WUSER_WIDTH : integer   := 0;
        C_S_AXI_RUSER_WIDTH : integer   := 0;
        C_S_AXI_BUSER_WIDTH : integer   := 0
        );
        port (
        S_AXI_ACLK  : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_ARESETN   : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_AWID  : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWADDR    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWLEN : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWSIZE    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWBURST   : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWLOCK    : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_AWCACHE   : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWPROT    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWQOS : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWREGION  : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWUSER    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_AWUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_AWVALID   : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_AWREADY   : out std_logic;
        S_AXI_WDATA : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_WSTRB : in std_logic_vector((C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_WLAST : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_WUSER : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_WUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_WVALID    : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_WREADY    : out std_logic;
        S_AXI_BID   : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_BRESP : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_BUSER : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_BUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_BVALID    : out std_logic;
        S_AXI_BREADY    : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_ARID  : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARADDR    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARLEN : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARSIZE    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARBURST   : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARLOCK    : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_ARCACHE   : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARPROT    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARQOS : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARREGION  : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARUSER    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ARUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_ARVALID   : in std_logic;
        S_AXI_ARREADY   : out std_logic;
        S_AXI_RID   : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ID_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_RDATA : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_RRESP : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_RLAST : out std_logic;
        S_AXI_RUSER : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_RUSER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXI_RVALID    : out std_logic;
        S_AXI_RREADY    : in std_logic
        );
    end component axitest_v1_0_S00_AXI;

begin

-- Instantiation of Axi Bus Interface S00_AXI
axitest_v1_0_S00_AXI_inst : axitest_v1_0_S00_AXI
    generic map (
        C_S_AXI_ID_WIDTH    => C_S00_AXI_ID_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH  => C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH  => C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_AWUSER_WIDTH    => C_S00_AXI_AWUSER_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_ARUSER_WIDTH    => C_S00_AXI_ARUSER_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_WUSER_WIDTH => C_S00_AXI_WUSER_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_RUSER_WIDTH => C_S00_AXI_RUSER_WIDTH,
        C_S_AXI_BUSER_WIDTH => C_S00_AXI_BUSER_WIDTH
    )
    port map (
        S_AXI_ACLK  => s00_axi_aclk,
        S_AXI_ARESETN   => s00_axi_aresetn,
        S_AXI_AWID  => s00_axi_awid,
        S_AXI_AWADDR    => s00_axi_awaddr,
        S_AXI_AWLEN => s00_axi_awlen,
        S_AXI_AWSIZE    => s00_axi_awsize,
        S_AXI_AWBURST   => s00_axi_awburst,
        S_AXI_AWLOCK    => s00_axi_awlock,
        S_AXI_AWCACHE   => s00_axi_awcache,
        S_AXI_AWPROT    => s00_axi_awprot,
        S_AXI_AWQOS => s00_axi_awqos,
        S_AXI_AWREGION  => s00_axi_awregion,
        S_AXI_AWUSER    => s00_axi_awuser,
        S_AXI_AWVALID   => s00_axi_awvalid,
        S_AXI_AWREADY   => s00_axi_awready,
        S_AXI_WDATA => s00_axi_wdata,
        S_AXI_WSTRB => s00_axi_wstrb,
        S_AXI_WLAST => s00_axi_wlast,
        S_AXI_WUSER => s00_axi_wuser,
        S_AXI_WVALID    => s00_axi_wvalid,
        S_AXI_WREADY    => s00_axi_wready,
        S_AXI_BID   => s00_axi_bid,
        S_AXI_BRESP => s00_axi_bresp,
        S_AXI_BUSER => s00_axi_buser,
        S_AXI_BVALID    => s00_axi_bvalid,
        S_AXI_BREADY    => s00_axi_bready,
        S_AXI_ARID  => s00_axi_arid,
        S_AXI_ARADDR    => s00_axi_araddr,
        S_AXI_ARLEN => s00_axi_arlen,
        S_AXI_ARSIZE    => s00_axi_arsize,
        S_AXI_ARBURST   => s00_axi_arburst,
        S_AXI_ARLOCK    => s00_axi_arlock,
        S_AXI_ARCACHE   => s00_axi_arcache,
        S_AXI_ARPROT    => s00_axi_arprot,
        S_AXI_ARQOS => s00_axi_arqos,
        S_AXI_ARREGION  => s00_axi_arregion,
        S_AXI_ARUSER    => s00_axi_aruser,
        S_AXI_ARVALID   => s00_axi_arvalid,
        S_AXI_ARREADY   => s00_axi_arready,
        S_AXI_RID   => s00_axi_rid,
        S_AXI_RDATA => s00_axi_rdata,
        S_AXI_RRESP => s00_axi_rresp,
        S_AXI_RLAST => s00_axi_rlast,
        S_AXI_RUSER => s00_axi_ruser,
        S_AXI_RVALID    => s00_axi_rvalid,
        S_AXI_RREADY    => s00_axi_rready
    );

    -- Add user logic here

    -- User logic ends

end arch_imp;
```

I thinkt that, it is here, in the end where I have to type my code related to the communication.

Comment: Your question is not very precise but yes, it is at the end of the block you have to add your logic (and also in entity ports). You also have signals to add in *axitest_v1_0_S00_AXI*.

Comment: I highly recommend you read up on the axi4 spec as there are many rules that need to be adhered to. You should be able top find the spec for free online.

Answer (score 0):

The wizard returns some template with the complete logic for an AXI4 device (same for AXI4Lite and Stream). All you have to is to place the logic, the parameter and the connections in the marked area.
So if you create a new IP, the wizard generates two files

- myip_v1_0
- myip_v1_0_S00_AXI

The first one is the top design, which you will see in the `Customization GUI` tab of the `Package IP` tab. You can add customization parameters like the bus width there. All you have to is to create a new generic in the entity. Your logic is placed in `myip_v1_0_S00_AXI`:

```
    -- Add user logic here
    << Logic here >>
    -- User logic ends

    port (
        -- Users to add ports here
        << Additional connections here >>
        -- User ports ends
        -- Do not modify the ports beyond this line

    generic (
        -- Users to add parameters here
        << Customization parameters here >>
        -- User parameters ends
        -- Do not modify the parameters beyond this line
```

Comment: Thank you Kampi for your answer. But I am still having my doubt related to how to read and write through AXI4 interface... Could you please type the shortest example in how to read and write? For example: write '1010' in memory through AXI4 and then, after 5 seconds, read that '1010' from memory through AXI4. It will be a **huge** help for me.